# Android OS can be used on desktop computers or laptops?

Tags: laptop, desktop, android, desktop-computer

Android OS can be used on desktop computers or laptops ? I mean like a windows or IOS or linux something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several projects that work on compiling the android OS to work on other platforms and hardware. For example, [androidx86](http://www.android-x86.org/) can run android on x86 computers, and [androidpi](http://androidpi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Pi_Wiki) can run android on raspberry pi

Usually, this kind of projects are made for nothing but just fun, or for testing applications. None of them are made for daily use.

Answer (score 0):

Android-x86 is an unofficial initiative to port Google's Android mobile operating system to run on devices powered by Intel and AMD x86 processors, rather than RISC-based ARM chips.

You can gain more insights into Android-x86 from their website [here](http://www.android-x86.org/).You can grab an installation image from their download section and there is also a howto section on installing android-x86.
you can try these ported android os in a hypervisor like virtual box or in actual system.